# Global variable in Laravel controllers and views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a group middleware with auth in Laravel 5.2,
and I want to have a global variable **$current_user**
that haves to be directly accesable in the controllers
and in the views.

I don't want do this every time in the controller methods:

```
$current_user   = Auth::user();
return view('account.view', ['current_user', $current_user]);
```

Is it possible to make a global variable for a authenticated user, what is the best option to do that?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done quite easily. You should have a controller that every other controller extends.

**app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

abstract class Controller
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $currentUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Grab the logged in user if any and set it to this property.
        // All extending classes should then have access to it.
        $this->currentUser = \Auth::user();

        // Share this property with all the views in your application.
        view()->share('currentUser', $this->currentUser);
    }
}
```

In your controllers you can just use `$this->currentUser` to access the logged in user. In your views you can just use `$currentUser` to access the logged in user. You only need to do this once in that one file because all of your controllers should extend `Controller`.